# Is it ok to replace a RAM that is PC4-21300 with DRAM (PC4-25600)?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm a novice at upgrading RAM. Is it ok to replace a PC4-21300 with DRAM (PC4-25600)? Will the difference between 21300 and 25600 do damage to my computer?

Comment: The memory will likely run at the lower frequency.  What goal are you trying to achieve by running the faster memory? Even if the memory runs at the higher frequency you unlikely will see ANY performance gains from such a small frequency difference

Comment: Check compatibility with the PC at a site such as Crucial's, https://www.crucial.com/store/advisor or Kingston's, https://www.kingston.com/en/configurator. If it's compatible with the PC, it likely would work - though at the speed of the slowest RAM on the PC.